# PLACEHOLDER - App Carmin.tv (prod)

Tags: app, placeholder

The App is for Prod environment

https://www.carmin.tv/

Carmin is a video platform of major french Scientific Institutes (IHES, CIRM, IHP, CIMPA) sharing contents from Research (courses, interviews, research presentations, ... mainly in mathematics, physics and biology)

This app allow registered visitors to ask questions about the scientific contents presented in a video.